# Apostrophe is HTML encoded in SharePoint List Item display form

Tags: sharepoint-server

In my SharePoint site I have list items with special characters in values. 
In the edit form and list views characters are rendered correctly. However in display form - "Apostrophe" (') is HTML encoded with ampersand.

The field in which characters are not rendered correctly is of "Choice" type with multi-selection enabled.

The current encoding is UTF-8 for the site.

What could be the reason for this issue?

Screenshot: Display Form
[image]

Screenshot: Edit form
[image]

Comment: Can you add any screenshots of your display and edit forms?

Comment: Added screenshots

Comment: This is strange. Is display form is SharePoint OOTB form or any other edited form?

Comment: OOTB display form